# lein clean temporary output folder

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I have the following in my **project.clj** file

```
:clean-targets [:target-path
                  :compile-path "classes"
                  :output-paths ["build/js/output" "js/output" "output"]
                  "build/js/main.js.map"
                  ]
```

.....

```
:output-to "build/js/main.js",
               :output-dir "build/js/output"
               :optimizations :simple,
               :source-map "build/js/main.js.map",
               :asset-path "js/out"
```

When trying to run `lein clean` the "build/js/output" file doesn't get deleted. Is the "output-dir" directory protected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `lein clean` removes only `target` directory. You can customize which directories should be cleaned by setting [`:clean-targets`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/2fb603b2bfc44255faf721995be1dc70d6ce388d/sample.project.clj#L320) in `project.clj`:

```
:clean-targets [:target-path "build/js/output"]
```

Comment: So i can clean "build" directory but not "build/js/output"? Doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Just change `build` to `build/js/output`.

Comment: cool! I was under the assumption I could have used an "array"